# Connecting to Azure VM using RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to access a VM from an RMI client in my machine using VM DNS NAME  and port 1099 after setting an endpoint with this port but I get a refused to connect to the VM. How can I tackle this problem?

this is the error I got

> D:\Dropbox\client\xxxxxxx>java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xx.xx.xx.xx -cp . client 
>   java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xx.xx.xx.xx; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: 
>   Connection timed out: connect at 
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source) at 
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source) at 
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source) at 
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
>   HelloImpl_Stub.getHelloMessage(Unknown Source) at 
>   client.main(client.java:18)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: 
>   Connection timed out: connect at 
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) at 
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) at 
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at 
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) at 
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at 
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at 
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at 
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at 
>   java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source) at 
>   java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source) at 
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source) at 
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source) ... 6 more

Comment: could yougive us some printscreens or logs ?